# Question about Natural Isomorphism in Definition of Tangent Spaces

Tags: smooth-manifolds

I am a new learner in manifolds and have several questions about proof of the following
Lemma:

**Lemma:**

$M_{m}$ is tangent space to a manifold $M$ at point $m$, and $F_{m}$ be the set of **germs vanishing at $m$**,  then $M_{m}$ is naturally isomorphic with $(F_{m}/F_{m}^{2})^{*}$

**Part of the proof:**

if $l\in$ $(F_{m}/F_{m}^{2})^{*}$, we define a tangent vector $v_{l}$ at m by setting

$v_{l}$=$l$({**f**-**f**(**m**)})  for **f**$\in$ $G_{m}$,

where **f**(**m**) denotes the germ of the function with the constant value **f**(m), $G_{m}$ being the set of germs at *m*, {}denoting the cosets in $(F_{m}/F_{m}^{2})^{*}$

It's clear that $v_{l}$ is linear and a derivation(process skimped).

Thus we obtain mappings of $M_{m}$ into $(F_{m}/F_{m}^{2})^{*}$ and vice versa.

**The following are my questions:**

(1)The quotient group $F_{m}/F_{m}^{2}$ is defined via plus rather than multiplication, is that correct?

(2)$l\in$ $(F_{m}/F_{m}^{2})^{*}$, that means $l$ maps a germ in $(F_{m}/F_{m}^{2})^{*}$ to a real number, so does $v_{l}$=$l$({**f**-**f**(**m**)}) mean that all the cosets of **f**-**f**(**m**) are mapped to the same number?

(3)The process mentioned about gives mappings of $(F_{m}/F_{m}^{2})^{*}$ to $M_{m}$, rather than $M_{m}$ into $(F_{m}/F_{m}^{2})^{*}$ as the author claimed.

Is my understanding correct? If not, would anyone help understand the proof?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Yes. $F_m$ is a vector space under pointwise addition of representing functions (but also an $\Bbb R$-algebra) and we want to obtain a vector space,  $M_m$. Of course the definition of $F_m^2$ uses the algebra structure (i.e., pointwise multiplication of representing functions). Note that for a general algebra $A$, it need nor be the case that $A^2$ is a vector subspace, but for $F_m$ this works.

(2) If $\mathbf f_1$ and $\mathbf f_2$ differ by a constant, then $\mathbf f_1-\mathbf f_1(m)=\mathbf f_2-\mathbf f_2(m)$ and hence $v_l(\mathbf f_1)=v_l(\mathbf f_2)$. But even if $\mathbf f_1,\mathbf f_2$ additionally differ by a product of germs vanishing at $m$, we have $v_l(\mathbf f_1)=v_l(\mathbf f_2)$ because $l$ evaluates on elements of $F_m/F_m^2$, not on elements of $F_m$ themselves.

(3) Yes, we obtain a linear map $(F_m/F_m^2)^*\to M_m$. An argument that this is an isomorphism is needed (by either specifying the inverse map or showing injectivity and surjectivity).